# IP address assignment issue

Tags: wifi, snow-leopard, macbook-pro, network

The problem is that I have a Macbook that keeps telling me another computer is using it's IP address. I normally don't have a problem with this as I'd either restart the computer, or router and it would obtain a new IP address.

However, every single IP address the computer is assigned is apparently taken by another computer. I can manually enter an IP and it is then immediately giving a warning about being taken by another computer. I have even left it on automatic DHCP, told the router to assign the computer an IP when DHCP is renewed. And when the computer renews, it says it's being used by another computer.

On the router there is Two other computers (labeled by names) and two android phones (also labeled by names). So I can tell which device is the only Mac on the network. None of the other devices's IPs match the Mac's. And the router states that the Mac's IP has been given the exact IP the Mac says is taken.

I'm not sure what is going on here. But I cannot figure out what the problem is.

So far I have restarted the router and Mac three times and tried to assign over 16 different unique IPs. The router still states the computer is connected and assigned a unique IP while the Mac says it's been assigned an IP that is used by another computer.

If there is anyone that can help with this issue, it would be very appreciative.

Comment: I've pointed this at a thread that covers duplicate IP pretty well. Please just edit this to make your situation clear/differentiated (different versions, specific router setup, explaining clearly why linked answers are not working for you) and we can easily remove the hold on this.

Comment: none of it helps. I was hoping this site would have been a helpful one. But even after stating I've done what that thread asked for one to do and saying it didn't help. I'm told to go back to that thread. I'm not in need of pointless loops, just answers.